Flux in spherical coordinates incorrect due to Jacobian term
I have the vector field $F(x, y, z) = (0, 0, z)$ and the spherical surface defined by $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 9$. I did this using spherical and without spherical coordinates, but it gave me a different result. The correct answer is $36\pi$, which is what I get without spherical coordinates.
I guess the problem I'm having is when parametrize $r(u, v) = (3\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta), 3\sin(\phi)sin(\theta), 3\cos(\phi) )$, and I calculate the Jacobian $|n| = \cfrac{\partial r}{\partial \theta} \times \cfrac{\partial r}{\partial \phi} = 3^2\sin(\phi)$, when I do the flux integral:
$$
\begin{align}
\Phi &= \int\int_SF(r(u, v)) \cdot |n|dS\\ &= \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi} (0, 0, 3\cos(\phi)) \cdot (-,-,3^2\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi))(3^2\sin(\phi))d\theta d\phi\\ &\neq 36\pi
\end{align}
$$
As I understand, by inspecting values, the problem is my Jacobian presence. The solution does not multiply by the Jacobian. But since I'm using spherical coordinates, shouldn't I multiply by the Jacobian to evaluate the integral? Why in this case the Jacobian is not being considered, as opposed to other change-of-variables problems? I may be misunderstanding something.

The problem is that you are using the wrong $n$ (the $z$ component is not like that), which is also not normalized by the way. You know that $n=r/||r||$, and $||r||=3$ of course, so the correct integral is:
$$ \int_0 ^\pi \int_0 ^{2 \pi} \overbrace{(0,0, 3 \cos(\phi))}^{=F} \overbrace{\cdot \frac{(-,-,3\cos(\phi)}{3}}^{= r/||r|| =n} 9\sin(\phi) d \theta d \phi= 54 \pi \int_0 ^\pi \cos(\phi)^2 \sin(\phi) d \phi= 36 \pi.$$
